# Array game solution without recreating array

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I am trying to create a program for one problem statement which is a game of array where 2 persons are playing a game for a given array with Person A moving first and the Person B playing their turns alternately.

In each turn, the length of the array decreases by 1 because of following operation that the player performs:
1. If the length of array is odd, the middle number is removed from array.
2. If the length is even, the player has a choice of removing either of the middle two elements.

The value of removed element is added to the score of the current player.
At end, the winner is decided by the one having maximum score. If both have same score at end, we allow Person A to win as he is the inventor of this game.
Both players play optimally.

I wrote a code for this but in my code I was actually modifying the existing array in each loop condition and it is a heavy operation which require more memory and time. In case the input is too large my program is taking more than 2 seconds to run. Is there any way to optimize the below code where we can avoid modifying/recreating a array.

```
class TestClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = s.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();

        }

        boolean aTurn = true;
        int aScore = 0, bScore = 0;
        int middle = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            int point = 0;
            int position = 0;
            int size = arr.length;
            if (size % 2 == 0) {

                middle = size / 2;

                if (arr[middle - 1] > arr[middle]) {
                    point = arr[middle - 1];
                    position = middle - 1;
                } else {
                    point = arr[middle];
                    position = middle;
                }
            } else {
                middle = (size) / 2;
                if (middle == 0) {
                    point = arr[0];
                    position = 0;
                } else {
                    point = arr[middle];
                    position = middle;
                }

            }

            arr = removeElement(arr, position);
            n--;

            if (aTurn) {
                aScore += point;
                aTurn = false;
            } else {
                bScore += point;
                aTurn = true;
            }

        }

        if (aScore == bScore) {
            System.out.println("Person_A 0");
        } else if (aScore > bScore) {
            System.out.println("Person_A " + (aScore - bScore));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Person_B " + (bScore - aScore));
        }

    }

    public static int[] removeElement(int[] original, int element) {
        int[] n = new int[original.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(original, 0, n, 0, element);
        System.arraycopy(original, element + 1, n, element, original.length - element - 1);
        return n;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could use a `LinkedList` to do the removal in O(1)

Comment: Have you considered using a `List` - more specifically a `LinkedList` as they are optimal for removal.

Comment: when the length is odd you should remove the middle element. For example when the length is 3, you should removed element with index 1 but you are removing element with index 3/2-1 which is 0. why that?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon get operation in linkedlist is more expensive. I tried to replace the array with linkedList where size of list was 100k. With Above code it took little over 2 seconds but with linkedlist it took 18 seconds. So linkedList cannot fit here.

Comment: @gagansingh yes , I think maybe I was trying something else and pasted that incorrect code. sorry for that. It should be middle only not the middle-1.

Comment: then I have a solution, that I will paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need is an array which can have a hole/gap in between and in every step the gap increases by 1. elements can be removed from either end of the gap only, not from any random position.

```
//an array which has a gap in between and
//elements can be removed from either end of the gap.
private static final class GapArray
{
    private final int[] array;
    private int gapStart;
    private int gapLength;

    private GapArray(int[] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.gapStart = array.length;
    }

    int get(int index)
    {
        checkBounds(index);
        if (index < gapStart)
        {
            return array[index];
        }
        else
        {
            return array[index + gapLength];
        }
    }

    private void checkBounds(int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size())
        {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
        }
    }
    //index is either just before start of the gap or just after end of gap.
    int remove(int index)
    {
        checkBounds(index);
        if (gapLength == 0)
        {
            gapStart = index;
            gapLength++;
            return array[gapStart];
        }
        else
        {
            if (index == gapStart - 1)
            {
                gapStart--;
                gapLength++;
                return array[gapStart];
            }
            else if (index == gapStart)
            {
                int value = array[gapStart + gapLength];
                gapLength++;
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("elements can be removed either end of the gap only");
            }
        }
    }

    int size()
    {
        return array.length - gapLength;
    }
}
```

With this data structure your code is as follows.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
//int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
//int[] arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

GapArray ca = new GapArray(arr);

boolean aTurn = true;
int aScore = 0;
int bScore = 0;

while (ca.size() > 0)
{
    int point;
    int size = ca.size();
    int middle;
    if (size % 2 == 0)
    {
        middle = size / 2;

        if (ca.get(middle - 1) > ca.get(middle))
        {
            point = ca.remove(middle - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            point = ca.remove(middle);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        point = ca.remove(size / 2);
    }
    if (aTurn)
    {
        aScore += point;
        aTurn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        bScore += point;
        aTurn = true;
    }
}
if (aScore == bScore)
{
    System.out.println("Person_A 0");
}
else if (aScore > bScore)
{
    System.out.println("Person_A " + (aScore - bScore));
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Person_B " + (bScore - aScore));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works well and optimized as well. I am above to get the response in milliseconds now even with large array size.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution that uses dynamic programming and works from reverse. Start playing the game in reverse. So in this case the elements are removed from the end. You actually do not have to remove the elements, just maintain indices of the new start and end. Try testing this one.

```
private static int[] method2(int[] arr)
{
    boolean evenSize = arr.length % 2 == 0;
    Score score = new Score(evenSize ? 1 : 0);
    int start = 0;
    int end = arr.length;
    while (start < end)
    {
        if (start + 1 == end)
        {
            score.addPoints(arr[start]);
            start++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[start] < arr[end - 1])
            {
                score.addPoints(arr[start]);
                start++;
                score.addPoints(arr[end - 1]);
                end--;
            }
            else
            {
                score.addPoints(arr[end - 1]);
                end--;
                score.addPoints(arr[start]);
                start++;
            }
        }
    }
    return score.score;
}

private static class Score
{
    int[] score = new int[2];
    int turn;

    Score(int turn)
    {
        this.turn = turn;
    }

    void addPoints(int point)
    {
        score[turn] += point;
        turn = (turn + 1) % 2;
    }
}
```